# Wix Installer what is "&lt;Install path&gt;"

Tags: wix

This is not my code, i do not understand what the installpath is between those escaped greater and smaller than signs.

```
<Control Id="SelectPathAndFeatures_Path" Type="Text" X="75" Y="200" Width="200" Height="20">
          <Text>&lt;Install path&gt;</Text>
          <Subscribe Event="SelectionPath" Attribute="Text" />
          <Subscribe Event="SelectionPathOn" Attribute="Visible" />
          <Condition Action="hide">Installed</Condition>
          <Condition Action="disable">Installed</Condition>
          <Condition Action="show">Not Installed</Condition>
          <Condition Action="enable">Not Installed</Condition>
        </Control>
```

Comment: Hi, If the answer was helpful, please except the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a normal regular text, that mean  < Install path > and that what you are going to see in the dialog.